# Differential Equations for Physicists

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, differential-equations

I find differential equations in physics to be quite challenging so I'm looking for a book to help me master them.

I'm familiar with solving ordinary differential equations via seperation of variables but haven't really gone much further than that.

I was thinking about buying this: https://www.waterstones.com/book/differential-equations-for-dummies/steven-holzner//9780470178140?awc=3787_1547914453_50402e12ab1b834f04a3a61a1372e9b2&utm_source=259955&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=Genie+Shopping

However I'm open to recommendations on books that are *specifically* targeted to physics, or will help me in general to solve any differential equation.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518442/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a self-learning person? Any university course of math and physics for physicists suffice to cope with your difficulties. However, and I can say it from my professional experience, the learning never ends. So be ready to learn from different sources, points of view, etc., etc.

Comment: Self-learning, although I'm doing A level physics (if you're from the UK), which isn't too heavy on the calculus

Comment: No, I am an ex-Russian, now French Physicist-Theorist, retired (jobless to be exact). 
The most difficult part is hidden: it is the limits of applicability of this or that equation, the inequalities present (often implicitly) in Physics and absent in the math.

Answer (score 0):

If you know calculus I think this book is just for you. I read most of the chapters as my Mathematical Methods in Physics Course. I think its highly student friendly. It has clear examples and then explains the usage of the equations in the physics area. It has also a pdf version.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JXSH5GG)

[Pdf version](http://mdudde.net/pdf/study_material_DDE/M.Sc.MAthematics/DIFFERENTIAL%20EQUATIONS.pdf)